# Angular: How to change the color of cell table if condition is true

Tags: html, angularjs, html-table, background-color

I have an object which has a variable called `changeColor`. In my html table I want to change the cell color if `changeColor` is true. I am using angular.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="list in results">
    <% if (!{{list.changeColor}} ) %>
    <% { %>
        <td bgcolor="red">{{list.value}}</td>
    <% } %>
    <td>{{list.price}}</td>
```

But after testing it is always red and the `<% if (! ) %> <% { %> <% } %>` is written in my html page! Can you please help me?

Tested this

```
<td style=".red {bgcolor: red;} .black {bgcolor: black;}"
 ng-class='{red : list.changeColor, black: !list.changeColor}'>
 {{list.price}}</td>
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to use `ng-class`

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in results">
    <td ng-class='{red : list.changeColor, black: !list.changeColor}'>{{list.value}}</td>
    <td>{{list.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.red {
    color: red; 
}

.black {
    color: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks Fizer Khan. How should .js file look like? I am new to angular

Comment: You do not need to do anything on javascript. I guess, you only want to change the color by boolean flag.

Comment: I did like this        `<td style=".red {bgcolor: red;} .black {bgcolor: black;}" ng-class='{red : list.changeColor, white: !list.changeColor}'>{{list.price}}</td>` the output of inspect element in html is like `ng-binding red` which is correct but bgcolor is not changed why?

Comment: The inline style is wrong. You have to place it inside the style tag. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Don't put so much logic in your views. Try this instead:

[ngClass directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

It will allow you to change the td class based on an expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <td ng-class="{'negative':daily.MTDCompSales<0,'positive':daily.MTDCompSales>0}">{{daily.MTDCompSales | number:0}}</td>
```

This line of code changes based on data value, if data is positive or negative

Comment: css file-
.negative{
     background-color: red

}

.positive{
     background-color: lime 

}