# Angular HTML - Change Table cell background-color based on boolean

Tags: html, css, angular

Trying to set the Table cell background-color using Angular ng-class.  I'm following snippets from these posts :

- [Angular: How to change the color of cell table if condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964641/angular-how-to-change-the-color-of-cell-table-if-condition-is-true)
- [Change HTML table cell background color using Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552504/change-html-table-cell-background-color-using-angular-js)
- Angular 9.1.3
- Material ~9.1.3

I've put my styles into the app.component.scss file :

```
.routeRed {
  background-color: red; 
}

.routeGreen {
  background-color: green;
}
```

I'm loading the app.component.scss file using standard Angular :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
```

And I've coded the app.component.html as follows : The <table> does sit within an Angular Material mat-tab, but I don't believe that is preventing any scss styles, at least I've not found anything that say Materials prevents this.

```
<table border="1" class="table" id="idTableCamelRoutes" matSort
    (matSortChange)="sortRoutes($event)" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th mat-sort-header="routeId">Route Id</th>
            ...Removed for brevity...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of applicationState.camelRoutes">
            <td>{{ item.routeId }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.routeStatus }}</td>
            <td ng-class="{'routeRed' : !(item.routeRunning), 'routeGreen': item.routeRunning}">{{item.routeRunning}}</td>
            <td>
```

The ngFor just iterates thru a collection of CamelRouteBean objects :

```
export class CamelRouteBean {
  routeId: string;
  routeStatus: string;
  routeRunning?: boolean;
  description?: string;
}
```

So, all I have to do is use item.routeRunning (a boolean) for the ng-class...I also verified that item.routeRunning IS being set to true or false just fine.  I verified that the app.component.scss IS being loaded as well.  But no matter what I try, the background-color of the Table Cell will not change from White.  When I inspect the Element in Chrome, I don't see any Style being applied at all to the table cell(s).

What am I missing?

tia adym

Comment: ng-class..? => [ngClass]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can something like below:

```
<div
  [ngClass]="{
  'routeGreen': item.routeRunning,
  'routeRed': !item.routeRunning
}"
></div>
```

Comment: OMG!  Both those posts code snippets have ng-class.  Anyway, TY!  It's working...

Answer (score -1):

I think it is a silly mistake. Change your ng-class to [ng-class]. For more details please check a stackbiltz example [LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-row-color-1bhvgo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)